# Different solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $y' = (y-x)^2$, I can substitute $u = y-x$ for an easy differential equation $$\frac{du}{dx}=u^2 -1$$

However, when I get up to the step $$\int \frac{1}{2\left(u+1\right)}+\frac{1}{-2\left(u-1\right)}\:du=x+C$$, I can either multiply up a $-2$ or a $+2$, which gives $y=\frac{2}{Ae^{-2x}-1}+1+x$ and $y=\frac{2}{1-Ae^{2x}}-1+x$ respectively. I suspect they are the same (they should be), but this time, I cannot prove or convinve myself that they are indeed the same. How can there be $e^{2x}$ and $e^{-2x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $$\int \frac1x dx\ne \ln x$$ but is instead $\ln|x|$. What it means is that your expression for $y$ depends on the value of $x$. You will need to explicitly write $$\left|\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right|=e^Ce^{2x}=Ae^{2x}$$ with $A>0$.

Comment: ok, I still dont see where the $e^{-2x}$ and $e^{2x}$ difference comes in though

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $Ae^{2x}$, then make a substitution $B=1/A$:$$\frac{Ae^{2x}+1}{Ae^{2x}-1}=\frac{1+Be^{-2x}}{1-Be^{-2x}}$$